# When using column-count attribute, first column is cut and second column starts with unwanted padding

Tags: html, css

I am creating a list of divs with css variables names using **column-count** attribute, first column is cut at the end (4px) and second column starts with small padding (4px). Do you know how to get rid of that and keep this functionality of splitting divs automatically into 2 columns?
[image]

```css
    .components {
        &__variable-list {
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 2rem;
        padding-bottom: .5rem;
      }

      &__variable {
          padding: .25rem .5rem;
          font-size: .875rem;

          &:nth-child(odd) {
              background-color: #e4e4e4;
          }

          &:nth-child(even) {
              background-color: #fff;
          }
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="components__variable-list">
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-border-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-focus-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-hover-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-active-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-active-border-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-heading-active-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-no-padding-active-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-no-padding-border-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-disabled-color</div>
    <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-single-color</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that if you add `break-inside: avoid;` to your `__variable` class like so:

```css
.components__variable-list {
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.components__variable {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
.components__variable:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

.components__variable:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="components__variable-list">
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-border-color</div>
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-color</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="components__variable-list">
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-border-color</div>
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-color</div>
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-border-color</div>
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-border-color</div>
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-color</div>
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-border-color</div>
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-border-color</div>
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-color</div>
  <div class="components__variable">--cwc-tab-border-color</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but with these styles when there are just 2 items, they are displayed under each other and not in 2 columns

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that, iI updated my post. now it is working with an odd and even number,  and two entries.

Comment: thanks man, that works fine, if you can give upvote to the question I would be very grateful, I am sick of that my votes don't count when I am using this platform